# error when using tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, errors, tcolorbox

I am trying to use the `tcolorbox` package and just by putting

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

into my code with no further instructions about the functions of the package I received the following error when compiling

```
Runaway argument?
{title/.store in=\kvtcb@title , notitle/.style={title=}, adjust text/\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@@qset was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.170   parskip/.style={before={\par
                                    \pagebreak[0]\noindent},after={\par}},
```

Could any one help me? I really want to use this package!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error using `tcolorbox` version `2.50`. Which version do you use?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are using an older version of `pgfkeys`. I do not get the error with TeX Live 2013.

The error message tells that `\pgfkeys@@qset` does not accept arguments that contain `\par` (`\long` arguments). This can be changed by the following redefinition:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,10pt]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfkeys@@qset
\expandafter#\expandafter1%
\expandafter#\expandafter2%
\expandafter#\expandafter3%
\expandafter{\pgfkeys@@qset{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Also further internal commands might not be defined with `\long`, then the trick can be used with these commands, too.